# why the telepresence 2 could not access the remote kubernetes cluster after connect

Tags: kubernetes, telepresence

I want to use `telepresence 2` to debug the app within remote kubernetes(v1.21) cluster in the Cloud. After installation of `telepresence 2` in `macOS Monterey`, I am using this command to connect to the remote kubernetes cluster:

```
telepresence connect
```

To my surprise, I could not ping any of the remote kuberentes pod after getting `telepresence 2` connected.

```
➜  ~ ping 10.97.196.216
PING 10.97.196.216 (10.97.196.216): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
^C
--- 10.97.196.216 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100.0% packet loss
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong or missing some ext configuration? this is the `telepresence 2` status output:

```
➜  ~ telepresence status
Root Daemon: Running
  Version   : v2.4.9 (api 3)
  DNS       :
    Remote IP       : 10.96.0.10
    Exclude suffixes: [.arpa .com .io .net .org .ru]
    Include suffixes: []
    Timeout         : 4s
  Also Proxy : (0 subnets)
  Never Proxy: (1 subnets)
User Daemon: Running
  Version           : v2.4.9 (api 3)
  Ambassador Cloud  : Logged out
  Status            : Connected
  Kubernetes server : https://126.104.83.161:6443
  Kubernetes context: context-reddwarf
  Telepresence proxy: ON (networking to the cluster is enabled)
  Intercepts        : 0 total
```

What should I do to make it work? I am using this command to test the connection:

```
➜  telepresence ping cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local
PING cruise-redis-master.reddwarf-cache.svc.cluster.local (10.108.202.100): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
```

and this is the resource infomation in cluster:

```
➜  telepresence kubectl get statefulsets -n reddwarf-cache -o wide
NAME                    READY   AGE    CONTAINERS   IMAGES
cruise-redis-master     1/1     276d   redis        docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r11
cruise-redis-replicas   3/3     276d   redis        docker.io/bitnami/redis:6.2.5-debian-10-r11
```

Comment: What cluster is used to connect to? Local (like minikube) or cloud managed or on-premise? Also based on docs I can see they `curl service-name`, not a direct pod's IP. Can you check it as well? [Reference](https://github.com/telepresenceio/telepresence#install-an-interceptable-service)

Comment: I tried the docs hello container it works fine. @moonkotte the curl command works fine but could not ping success.